# Timed switch between 2 psus

Tags: power-supply, relay, timer

Lets say we're in a car application, for the sake of argument.

We've got the 12v cigarette lighter adapter line (which is turned on when the car is on and off when the car is off), a 12v line straight to the car battery, and a separate 12v battery pack.

I want to use relays and a timer circuit to do the following (which I had a hard time putting in standard English), assume 12V-A = Cig Adapter, 12V-B = 12V line to car battery (always on/available), and BatPack = Separate 12v battery pack (always on/available):

```
    If (12V-A = on) then
    {
     BatPack = off;
     12V-B = on;
    }

    Elseif (12V-A = off) then
    {
     BatPack = on;
     wait(5s);
     12V-B = off;
     wait(55s);
     BatPack = off;
    }
```

If someone could point me in the right direction or provide circuitry, that would be awesome! I'm doing this not only to expand my understandings of analog circuitry, but to also be actually used in an application I have in mind.

If it's not too hard, the Elsif could be changed to:

```
Elseif (12V-A = off) then 
{ 
 BatPack = on; 
 if(12V-A = off) then { 
  wait(5s); 
  12V-B = off;  
  wait(55s); 
  BatPack = off;
 } 
}
```

Comment: I also understand that this would complicate the circuitry, but if possible the Elseif could be changed to:
    Elseif (12V-A = off) then
    {
     BatPack = on;
     if(12V-A = off) then
     {
      wait(5s);
      12V-B = off;
      wait(55s);
      BatPack = off;
     }
    }

Comment: You probably should edit your question with that extra bit instead of make a comment. Another thing that will likely affect the answer to mention is whether the device being powered is a 3rd party device, or say a microcontroller of your own design / programming where it could initiate the shutdown after 60 seconds using an I/O pin.

Comment: @PeterJ The device is a 3rd party device that can only be turned on and off.

Comment: What does "12V-B = off" actually mean? Isn't it an input, which is on all the time?

Comment: @pjc50, no 12V-B is a _available_ all the time, but is not _on_ all the time. Its a power source which will need to be switched off after the battery pack has been on for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a little searching I found what I wanted. I took two circuits and carefully fused (read:mashed) them together, simulated them and got a working solution. Basically I found a circuit to delay the turning off 12V-B relay and turning on the Batter Pack relay for a set amount of time.

This circuit will also allow the 12V-B relay to turn back on if the 12V-A relay is activated again. So, I have not only answered my original question, but the extra portion as well.

Note: I just realized that you can't read C2 (2.2uF) and D3 (1N4148).
Note 2:R6, R8, and C3 control the length of time the Batter Pack is on & C1 and R2 control the time delay for the U4 relay turn off. Where the voltage pins are, those are the outputs, I haven't figured out all the nuances of Cadence yet.

[image: Schematic]
[image: Battery Pack on Response]
[image: 12V Constant Response]

Combined Response, both voltage outputs were paralled before ground
[image: Combined Response, both voltage outputs were paralled before ground]

Picture quality may be crud, however I can provide better pics if someone wants them.

Delay came from [Generate DC pulse after switch turned off?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56699/generate-dc-pulse-after-switch-turned-off/56718#56718)